# Must train and test data have the same exact features?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Let's say we want to predict goals scored by both of the teams in a game of football. And let's say that our training data is going to contain: team1, team2, team1 goals, team2 goals, score, winner.

My understanding is that the testing data has to have the same amount of features as the training data, and that test data can only contain "input" and not output.

So does that mean that we cant train our model with those features since we do not know how many goals are scored before the game has started?

Comment: Test data should contain the same amount of features - [target].

Comment: And while you do not know number of goals before the game you can not use them in training. But you can try to predict them too. And use predictions as features.